# Accidentally answer two times on 1 question, does deleting 1 of my answer affects me in any manner?

Tags: discussion

Due to internet connection I think my answer has been duplicated, and I am thinking if I should delete the other one, but I'm afraid that it may affect my reputation or it may affect my ability to post question.

**Edit:**

This is [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27457469/how-to-recreate-page-scroll-behavior-in-googles-inbox-page/27458623#27458623)

Comment: From what I can see (can't see deleted posts) you are not endangered to get into a ban. IMHO you should delete one of the posts, one will be removed anyway over the time.

Comment: As long there aren't any upvotes on any of them currently, I can't see any concerns about rep if you just delete one of them.

Comment: Your answer [*has* been duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27458623/82548); you should delete one of them.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just being careful because I am now really afraid to be ban again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you posted an duplicate to your first answer, chances are that **if you leave it threre it *is* going to affect your reputation or have other effects on your standing.** People are going to see the duplicate and perhaps downvote it as "not useful" (since you've **already** posted the same answer) and most likely flag it for moderator attention. **Ultimately, it will be deleted by a moderator.**

So delete the duplicate, since it cannot be worse than leaving it there.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Thanks! I deleted the duplicated answer now. Thanks!

Comment: @CaryBondoc: Also, you might want to reduce the double you delete to a pithy explanation like "Removed accidental double-post." Thus, 10K-users won't wonder what that one is about.